# Is Sbt fundamental architecture based on GNU make command?

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt command architecture is a bit strange and hard to understand.
But one day, I found that Sbt's task is very similar to GNU make's target.
Both need dependency declaration and we don't know real task/target running order. Its optimization is command's job.

Sbt is based on GNU Make, is this right ?
Can I say that Sbt is like a GNU Make to Scala/Sbt newcomer ?

Comment: I'm old maven user and sbt for me is interactive maven/gradle.

Comment: What do you mean by "based on"? They're both build tools that maintain dependency graphs, and Make came first. This is a pretty vague question that's unlikely to be helpful to anyone as it's currently written.